# Facebook Authorize not working on free version of app

Tags: facebook, ios5

I have a free and paid version of my app on itunes but as the free version has in app purchase I cant use the same bundle id across the two apps and therefore the only way I can see of adding facebook to the free app is having a second facebook app registered?

I have done this but for some reason when calling [facebook authorize: permissions] my app boots up the facebook app but returns straight away to my app, not getting in to any of the handleOpenUrl functions or even asking the user for permissions. The code is identical line by line to the paid version of my app with the only difference being the appID that is used. Any ideas what would cause this? Facebook did work on both apps until the recent updates.

After further playing around with this code I have found it works if I tell it to not use the FB App and to instead use safari authorisation. Still failing to see why I can use the app on one app but not another :s

Answer (score 1):

Log in to [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and check your iOS bundle ID for your free app carefully.  Make sure the bundle ID you tell Facebook is exactly what your app thinks it is.  If it's not identical, the new Facebook app will not allow your app to authenticate.

Comment: It is the same, why would it work through safari but not through the FB App?

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago, and it was an uppercase/lowercase mismatch on one letter in my bundle ID.  The app had added a layer of error checking that the web interface didn't have.  Facebook continues to try to tighten up their codebase, and features roll out unevenly across their various elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple iOS apps use the same Facebook app.  Check this link..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#multipleapps

**There are three steps:**

1. Add the additional bundle id in your apps "iOS Bundle ID" file in your faceBook app settings.
2. Then in your iOS apps, use the 'urlSchemeSuffix' option in the 'initWithAppId' method.
3. Modify the URL Schemes property in the info.plist.

The link explains it in detail.  No need to register a 2nd app with Facebook.

Hope this helps.